# Add to end of a single linked list Segmentation fault C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a c application which adds elements at the end of a single linked list but I get a segmentation fault after i read the last element.

I use function `addAtEndSLL()` to add an element at the end.

```
//Program to add elements at the end of a single linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Basic declaration of a SLL
struct singleList{
    int data;
    struct singleList *next;
};

//Add an element at the end of a SLL
int addAtEndSLL(struct singleList **startPtr, int value){
    struct singleList *newNode;
    newNode = (struct singleList *)malloc(sizeof(struct singleList));
    if(newNode == NULL){
        printf("\nFailed to Allocate Memory");
        return;
    }

    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if(*startPtr == NULL){
        *startPtr = newNode;
    } else {
        struct singleList *temp = NULL;
        temp = *startPtr;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, value;
    struct singleList *first = NULL, *tempS = NULL;
    tempS = first;
    for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        printf("\nEnter the data:");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        addAtEndSLL(&first, value);
    }

    /*****This is where I belive the segfault occurs*****/

    while(tempS->next != NULL){
        printf("%d", tempS->data);
        tempS = tempS->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the warnings: make your function `void` instead of `int`, and remove the last `return`, which now becomes unnecessary.

Next, to the real problem in your code: when you set `start` inside your `addAtEndSLL` function, the value of `first` remains the same, because C passes parameters by value; that includes pointers.

To fix this issue, change the function to accept a pointer to pointer (i.e. double asterisk), pass `&first` instead of `first` to it, and add an extra level of dereference to the parameter inside `addAtEndSLL`:

```
void addAtEndSLL(struct singleList **startPtr, int value) {
    ...
    // Change all uses of start with *startPtr, like this:
    if(*startPtr == NULL){
        *startPtr = newNode;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for such a fast answer. I changed all uses of start with *startPtr , changed the type of function from int to void and passed &first instead of first, but I still get the segfault after I introduce the values.

Comment: @CunaChristian Move `tempS = first` assignment to after the first loop, and check `tempS != NULL` instead of `tempS->next != NULL` in the second `while` loop ([demo](http://ideone.com/pJ4DAA)).